# Need assistance with batch variables and substrings

Tags: batch-file

i have issues with %arch:~1,3% showing up correctly
echoing %arch:~1,3% outputs x64 like it should
but when used as a variable it messes everything up

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Color 0A
cls
title PORTABLE LASTPASS LAUNCHER

:ARCHCHECK
cls
set arch=
if exist "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%" set "arch=_x64" & goto LASTPASSCHECK

:LASTPASSCHECK
cls
if not exist .\bin\lastpass\lastapp%arch%.exe goto FILECHECK
if not exist .\bin\lastpass\lastapphook%arch%.dll goto FILECHECK
goto WGETUPDATE

:FILECHECK
cls
if not exist .\extra\lastappinstall%arch%.exe goto DOWNLOADLASTPASS
if not exist .\bin\7-ZipPortable\7-ZipPortable.exe goto 7ZIPINSTALLERCHECK
.\bin\7-ZipPortable\App\7-Zip%arch:~1,3%\7z.exe e .\extra\lastappinstall%arch%.exe lastapp%arch%.exe -o.\bin\lastpass\
.\bin\7-ZipPortable\App\7-Zip%arch:~1,3%\7z.exe e .\extra\lastappinstall%arch%.exe lastapphook%arch%.dll -o.\bin\lastpass\
goto LASTPASSCHECK

:DOWNLOADLASTPASS
cls
if exist lastappinstall%arch%.exe goto MOVELASTPASS
if not exist .\bin\wget.exe call :DOWNLOADWGET
.\bin\wget.exe https://lastpass.com/download/cdn/lastappinstall%arch%.exe

:MOVELASTPASS
cls
move lastappinstall%arch%.exe .\extra\lastappinstall%arch%.exe
goto FILECHECK
```

the output i get when used as a variable is that it thinks it says "ziparcharcharch" somehow :/

Comment: BTW Your `if exist` in :ARCHCHECK is useless when jumping to the next line where program flow reaches nevertheless.

Comment: its made as if there is not that directory its automatically "" aka nothing because there is no extension like _x64 on the 32bit version of lastpass.

Comment: thats why arch is set arch=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it myself
instead of %arch:~1,3% i shouldve put %arch:~2,2% as i want two skip to characters and print the next 2
i.e. instead of _x64 turning into x64 it turns into 64